# Firefox issue with html injection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I am trying to inject an href url into a div, this code works perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox, any pointers as to why? Thanks.

Html -

```
<div id="content"></div>
<style>

    embed, object {
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

JQuery -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("li.sub-level3").click(function () {

                var hrefValue = $(this).children().clone().attr("href");

                history.pushState(null, null, hrefValue);
                $("#content").html('<object data=' + hrefValue + ' />').css("min-height", "1000px");

               $("p").css("display", "none")
               $("#cookie-bar").css("display", "none")

            });
 });
</script>
```

The console says 'o is undefined' in the following function -

```
prepareTx: function(e, t) {

        var i, s, n, a, r, o = this.opts();
        return o.slideCount < 2 ? void(o.timeoutId = 0) : (!e || o.busy && !o.manualTrump || (o.API.stopTransition(), o.busy = !1, clearTimeout(o.timeoutId), o.timeoutId = 0), void(o.busy || (0 !== o.timeoutId || e) && (s = o.slides[o.currSlide], n = o.slides[o.nextSlide], a = o.API.getSlideOpts(o.nextSlide), r = o.API.calcTx(a, e), o._tx = r, e && void 0 !== a.manualSpeed && (a.speed = a.manualSpeed), o.nextSlide != o.currSlide && (e || !o.paused && !o.hoverPaused && o.timeout) ? (o.API.trigger("cycle-before", [a, s, n, t]), r.before && r.before(a, s, n, t), i = function() {
            o.busy = !1, o.container.data("cycle.opts") && (r.after && r.after(a, s, n, t), o.API.trigger("cycle-after", [a, s, n, t]), o.API.queueTransition(a), o.API.updateView(!0))
        }, o.busy = !0, r.transition ? r.transition(a, s, n, t, i) : o.API.doTransition(a, s, n, t, i), o.API.calcNextSlide(), o.API.updateView()) : o.API.queueTransition(a))))
    },
```

Comment: whats the console in FF saying? Also try using`$("li.sub-level3").on('click',function(){` in place of: `$("li.sub-level3").click(function () {`

Comment: Hi atoms the console - TypeError: o is undefined[Learn More]  app.min.js:1:4333
 e.fn.cycle.API.prepareTx app.min.js:1:4333
 e.fn.cycle.API.queueTransition/s.timeoutId<

Comment: where's 'o' in your code?

Comment: Hi Atoms please see edited post

Comment: try this: `history.pushState({}, '', hrefValue);`

Comment: Hi DomeTune I get the same error with this.

Comment: whats the name of that script?

Comment: cycle2.js and cycle2.swipe.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi according to netmarketshare.com/… theres only 0.57% users that use Firefox mobile/tablet.

I guess its not worth worrying about with such a small percentage therefore my solution is to alert the user (if they are using Firefox on mobile/tablet) to use another browser.

Anyone objecting to this please let me know so that I can review the solution.

Thanks for the replies.